# What is the "2001 article" for blocking "automated retrieval programs" referred to by the wget man page?

Tags: wget, man, documentation

The `wget` man page states this, under the section for the `--random-wait` parameter:

```
    Some web sites may perform log analysis to identify retrieval
    programs such as Wget by looking for statistically significant
    similarities in the time between requests. [...]

    A 2001 article in a publication devoted to development on a popular
    consumer platform provided code to perform this analysis on the
    fly.  Its author suggested blocking at the class C address level to
    ensure automated retrieval programs were blocked despite changing
    DHCP-supplied addresses.
```

I want to obtain a copy of this article for reading, and have tried many searches on the Internet to determine the article. However, all I can find with these searches is the man page for `wget` hosted on different websites; and some other research papers having no relation at all with this topic.

Does anyone know which article is being referred to and where I can obtain a copy?

Comment: I was digging through the wget mailing list and found this: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2015-05/msg00029.html

Answer (score 14):

Even though not a direct answer, `git blame` and `git log` reveal that this section was introduced in commit [2c41d783](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/?id=2c41d783c62f1252701b8cb5a8adbcf8efbf0275) by a committer called `hniksic`, who turns out to be Hrvoje Niksic.  His email address can be found in wget's `ChangeLog` file (I won't publish it here for the obvious reasons).  I'd suggest asking him directly, as he might be the best to give a more adequate answer.  While at it, you might consider asking him whether he would mind updating the manpage accordingly. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be this article:

[Creating meaningful data from web logs using base SAS](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/018-29.pdf)

There's a paragraph discussing blocking of class C ranges:

> Once the IP address is separated into its components the filtering of
>   ranges of IP addresses is simple. A class B filter is done against the
>   first two octets, e.g. 168.126.xx.xx. This is variable Onetwo in the
>   code example above. Class C ranges are more commonly used as they
>   target entire servers and use three of the four octets, e.g.
>   168.126.56.xx. In the code sample above, this the field Three
>   given that Usrhost is the web log’s TCP/IP address value.

And one mentioning `wget` in user agent string-based blocking:

> Our preferred method for user agent string identification utilizes the
>   index pattern matching function. For example:
>
> ```
> if index(lowcase(agentstr), 'keynote') or
> index(lowcase(agentstr), 'sureseeker') or
> index(lowcase(agentstr), 'wget') or
> ```

It was the fifth result in [Googling for "log analysis wget" for the year 2001](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=log%20analysis%20wget&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2001%2Ccd_max%3A2001).